# After migrate svn repositories to another server in conf folder passwd file is empty

Tags: linux, svn, configuration, svn-repository

After migrating svn repos from a server to another server, even I used "--force-uuid" in svnadmin load command, the passwd files of the repositories are empty.
All conf folder contents are empty.

Is there a way to migrate conf file properly?

Thanks for your help.

edit: from server's svn version is 1.6, to server's svn version is 1.7. is version difference causes a problem like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> edit: from server's svn version is 1.6, to server's svn version is
>   1.7. is version difference causes a problem like this?

You must not use Subversion 1.7 or older versions. Upgrade to the latest 1.9.x.

I would recommend that you read the documentation *before* you perform any repository maintenance or administration tasks. [SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/index.html) is a great resource of information about Subversion and version control in general. It will help you familiarize yourself with common terminology and concepts of SVN and version control.

> After migrating svn repos from a server to another server, even I used
>   "--force-uuid" in svnadmin load command, the passwd files of the
>   repositories are empty. All conf folder contents are empty.

Read [SVNBook | Repository data migration using svnadmin](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate.svnadmin):

> The Subversion repository dump format describes versioned repository
>   changes only. It will not carry any information about uncommitted
>   transactions, user locks on filesystem paths, repository or server
>   configuration customizations (including hook scripts), and so on.

And note that [UUID](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.uuids) has nothing to do with your htpasswd file.